# How to make a html button change when clicked

Tags: html

I am trying to create a button that is called 'Follow', but changes to 'Unfollow' when clicked in HTML. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div>
  <button routerLink="/settings" mat-raised-button color="primary">Follow Topic</button>
</div>
```

How to I add this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

HTML probably would not be an advisable way to do this. You would be better served by using the JavaScript [onClick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event. I would also assume there's going to be more going on behind the scenes when a user clicks on the button, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

We can use onClick attribute to call a function, which checks what state the button is in, and changes it accordingly.

```js
  function toggle(el) {
    if (el.innerText=='Follow Topic') {
        el.innerText='Unfollow'
      } else {
        el.innerText='Follow Topic'
      }
    }
```

```html
  <div>
    <button routerLink="/settings" mat-raised-button color="primary" onClick="toggle(this)">
       Follow Topic
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: So, would this ensure that if the button is clicked again, it will revert back to 'Follow'?